# How to find distance between already saved lat and long and user current lat long in dynamodb aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I already have table called location  that contains lat and long of hotel and the details, i need query to find the distance between user current location and already saved hotel lat long if less than 25kms show result in dynamoDb,

Am new to dynamoDb already i done this with mysql find distance and having used to make that 25kms condition,

Thanks in advance. i struggling with this 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

No such function exists in DynamoDB. You would need to do the math to calculate the distance between the 2 coordinates yourself

Comment: Oh But if table have 100000 records mean we took each record and perform query its take more time

Comment: That is correct. DynamoDB has no geospatial functions though, so you don't have any other option with DynamoDB. You could use ElasticSearch alongside DynamoDB and it to do geospatial queries.

Comment: are you using javascript or java ?